# Python: How to check that two CSV files with header rows contain same information disregarding row and column order?

Tags: python, unit-testing, csv

For unit testing a method, I want to compare a CSV file generated by that method (the actual result) against a manually created CSV (the expected result).

The files are considered equal, if the fields of the first row are exactly the same (i.e. the headers), and if the remaining row contain the same information.

The following things must not matter: order of the columns, order of the rows (except for the header row), empty lines, end-of-line encoding, encoding of boolean values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is late, so I'll sketch the solution

1. input data using `csv.reader`, compare the headers, normalize booleans
2. temporarily transpose the two lists of lists and sort them on the header, something like

   ```
   cols = zip(*data)
   data = zip(*sorted(cols))
   ```

   repeated for the two data sets, so that now the columns are aligned in the two data sets
3. compare row by row the two data sets.

Comment: I ended up with a slightly different solution: After reading and normalizing the data, the expected and the actual are each stored in a list of dictionaries. These are then compared by the `unittest.assertItemsEqual()` function.

Answer (score 1):

> store in a dictionary with corresponding head of csv file as key and first row as values
>   read the second file and check against with dictionary.

Comment: The dictionary approach seems to be the right path to go. Unfortunately, it does not work for the boolean values, as they can be encoded as `'True'`, `'TRUE'` or `'true'` which are different strings and therefore are not equal.

Comment: @ThS the booleans are sprayed all over or constitute the content of a number of boolean columns?

Comment: @black star The booleans appear in columns that have a header that starts with 'is*', such as 'is_done'.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest use this method::

```
>>> import pyexcel as pe
>>> expected_sheet = pe.load("expected.csv", name_columns_by_row=0)
>>> actual_sheet = pe.load("actual.csv", name_columns_by_row=0)
>>> assert actual_sheet.to_dict() == expected_sheet.to_dict() # where to_dict() returns
>>> # an ordered dict of the content
```